# Sound/Video playing in slow motion on 12.04 with Bluetooth + Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: 12.04, sound, google-chrome, bluetooth, youtube

I have been using the same Plantronics BT Headset with my HP laptop and BT USB dongle running 12.04 since 12.04 came out. Just in the last week or two I have started to have a problem where playing sound through the headset when in Chrome causes the sound (and video if watching Youtube or similar) to play in slow motion. If I switch off of the BT headset and keep playing the sound, it stays in slow motion. If I refresh the page, it plays properly. I've noticed this happening with Google Hangouts too.

Trying things in FF seems to be fine, and switching Youtube to HTML5 doesn't seem to help. This problem seems to coincide with a change to Ubuntu that has given me two BT icons in my task bar instead of one. I tried researching why that happened and came up empty there too. This could be a straight up chrome issue, but I thought I would go the Ubuntu + BT route for investigation first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has seemingly gone away with recent updates, so lets hope it stays that way!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. To add to the problem:

If I'm playing a clip and I switch audio outputs to the BT headset, the continues to play normally, but when I refresh the page or go to a different clip, it goes to slow motion again.

Comment: Rich, I see that same behaviour as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to bet that this issue is somehow related to configuration issues with pulse or alsa. I have an HP DV7 with Beats audio, and I have been spending a huge amount of time messing with audio config files to get my built in subwoofer to work with all of my other speakers. I can usually get some combination of them to work, but not all of them at the same time yet. At any rate, my computer also has a built in bluetooth module, and I use LG HBS-700 bluetooth headphones(awesome headphones BTW). Normally audio works properly out of the box, but after I start messing with stuff, I start to get this issue. Audio plays normally out of speakers(after refresh like OP), but bluetooth sounds heavily distorted. Unfortunately, I do not know much about the principles behind the linux audio system, but if somebody does, let us know so we can start working on this thing.